# Android resource linking failed. Image is present in all drawable folders but the error says it is not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I already have the images in my drawable folders. They were working earlier but now it shows that the resource is not found. This is basically with all images.

I am using `ImageView` and `android:src=@drawable/filename`

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: Any solution found? as I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with the new version of Android Studio (3.3). If you just updated the software and suddenly it stops working, open your `build.gradle` file and remove this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // This line here
    }
    ...
```

It fixed the issue for me.